# Java webdriver for angular application not protractor?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, protractor

I will be responsible for test automation for angular application. I know that we have a protractor tool but i prefer webdriver with java(feel better with this than javascript and protractor). May i use java with webdriver or i must do it using protractor because selenium will not handle it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, *you can still use the regular Java selenium bindings to test AngularJS applications*. It's just that `Protractor` is simply more suitable/convenient to use for specifically AngularJS applications because of the several unique things it provides:

- it works *in sync with Angular* - it always knows when Angular is "ready" to be interacted with
- it provides Angular specific locators like [`by.model`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.model), [`by.binding`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.binding), [`by.repeater`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.repeater) etc
- it allows you to easily [mock AngularJS modules](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=Protractor.prototype.addMockModule) on the fly
- it is developed and supported by Google developers (and of course the github community) - meaning it is in sort of a sync with Angular development cycle
- it has a very nice and documented API
- and many more

It's also important to understand that `Protractor` is actually a wrapper around the `WebDriverJS` - JavaScript selenium bindings. And, as a side note, `Protractor` can also be used to test non-angular apps (just turn the sync off).

---

There is also [`ngWebDriver`](https://github.com/paul-hammant/ngWebDriver) package that might actually be your solution:

> We have taken JavaScript from Angular's Protractor project. While
>   ngWebDriver perfectly compliments the Java version of WebDriver, it
>   has to pass JavaScript up to the browser to inteoprate with Angular,
>   and the Protractor project has done the hard work (including testing)
>   to make that solid, and ngWebDriver benefits from that work.

---

Also see:

- [Use protractor with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29983241/use-protractor-with-java)
- [how to implement protractor JavaScript API in Java to use in existing Selenium Java Frameworks](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1746)