# Why to choose JavaScript as a language for UI test automation?

Tags: javascript, protractor, automated-tests, ui-automation

JavaScript UI automation frameworks such as Protractor involves working on asynchronous execution, promises, callbacks, anonymous functions, etc  which are probably an overkill for a straight forward task like UI test automation which is basically an sequential activity like finding an object and perform operations on it.

If we can handle AngularJS/other front-end web application development JavaScript framework pages in non JavaScript based automation frameworks then why should we go for JavaScript frameworks ?

Or may be use porting of frameworks like protractor in languages like ruby/python which are simple,readable , user friendly so better suitable for UI test automation?

Note: I am not against JavaScript or its frameworks like Protractor(in fact I have designed automation frameworks for multiple large projects using protractor successfully), but I want to understand the trade-off of choosing JavaScript as a language for test automation?

Comment: Well, if you work with javascript, in most cases it's a language you already know well. So why go for a language like say, java, which you may know much worse? Just stick to the language you know and work with.

Comment: Your question is extremely vague, what do you want to know? If you want to test AngularJS extensively Protractor works very well together. What alternatives did you have in mind?

Comment: We actually have a separate Test automation team writing tests for our angular app. Protractor can actually be written in other languages like Java. I'm really missing the point of this question.

Comment: Mathias, I want to understand why should we use JavaScript as UI test automation language ?

Comment: Because UI tests interact with the browser, and to manipulate things on the page you need to use JavaScript

Comment: @VishalAggarwal .. May be starting a bounty would help get more attention ..  was wondering if there are more answers possible

Comment: Gunderson, but selenium bindings do exist in other languages which also interact with page 's JavaScript.I think as Mathias suggested, it is possible to implement protractor in languages like python out ruby which are better suited for straghtforward tasks  UI test automation ...Do you agree???

Comment: I think choosing Javascript for your tests makes sense if your front-end or backend is written in Javascript (Node.js). Developers are already familiar with the language and they are already writing unit tests in Javascript. So choosing Javascript for browser level automation is a no brainer. More interesting question to me is why is every method in Protractor implemented with promises. That seems like an overkill for a framework which most of the time needs to locate an element on a page and perform some action on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's typical to choose Protractor or another JavaScript based testing framework when testing a JavaScript application because, plainly stated, most people find it easiest to test their JavaScript with more JavaScript, just as you'd typically write unit tests for your server-side code in the same server-side language you're coding in. If you, on the other hand, *don't* find that easier and have some other testing scheme that you find more intuitive, you're perfectly allowed to strike out on your own and use whatever technology you like. It's that simple!

Comment: Even for JavaScript applications, it is far easier to write code in languages like ruby or python because of the absence of asynchronous nature.My point is asynchronous nature might be an very useful feature for web application development however for UI test automation , it is not at all required.

Comment: Does that contradict anything I said? My point is that generally, people test using a particular framework because either they or the person who picked their employer's tech stack believed it's the best fit for their needs. That's all there is to it!

Answer (score 5):

I have explained below a case study **Advantages of Protractor over Java-Selenium for testing AngularJs Applications**

But you can apply this as a generic rule how Javascript based frameworks understand Angular better than other frameworks. This is an excerpt from my [blog post on the same](https://testautomation-aditya.com/2016/08/16/advantages-of-protractor-over-selenium-for-testing-angularjs-applications/)

This answers the eternal questions that Test Engineers have.

1.Why should we move from Java-Selenium to NodeJs-Protractor?

2.Is it worth the effort?

3.What does Protractor offer more?

4.Whats the big deal about Protractor?

5.Are you frustrated with all waits & sleeps in your code?

These are advantages Protractor offer over Selenium

**1.Understands the Angular life-cycle**

Protractor was made by people who created AngularJs and it understands and waits for the AngularJs to be bootstrapped.These applications have a lot running in background without any visible behavior change in browser and make life hell for Selenium to understand and synchronize.Thus scripts made in selenium end up having clumsy waits & sleeps.

`browser.waitForAngular()`
[This](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBrowser.prototype.waitForAngular) instructs webdriver to wait until Angular has finished rendering and has no outstanding $http or $timeout calls before continuing.

Note that Protractor automatically applies this command before every WebDriver action.

**2.Provides additional element detection techniques**

Protractor provides angular specific locator strategy.They provide options to select elements by angular models, bindings, ng-options – and finding elements inside ng-repeat.

HTML Element on the Application page:

`<pre><code>
<div>
 <span ng-bind="firstName" class="ng-binding">Sachin</span>
<br>
<span ng-bind="lastName" class="ng-binding">Tendulkar</span>`

Element location in Protractor `element(By.binding('user.firstName'))`

Element location in Selenium: There is no unique way to identify this element in Selenium and have to depend on identifying any unique neighboring element and provide a relative path.

Some extra [element locato](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBy)r techniques provided by Protractor

`binding –                            Find an element by text binding.
exactBinding –                  Find an element by exact binding.
model –                               Find an element by ng-model expression.
buttonText –                      Find a button by text.
partialButtonText –         Find a button by partial text.
repeater –                            Find elements inside an ng-repeat.
exactRepeater –                 Find an element by exact repeater.
cssContainingText –        Find elements by CSS which contain a certain string.
options –                             Find an element by ng-options expression.
deepCss –                            Find an element by css selector within the Shadow DOM.`

Comment: Aditya, if look at the question deeply it is not about protractor, it is more about choosing JavaScript for test automation on the fundamental level...

Comment: Yes .. This answers the specific case - Selenium WebDriver - Java Over Protractor-JavaScript .. You can extrapolate this to your question .. This shows the advantage javascript solutions offer as they understand Angular better

Comment: OK...So Aditya, can't protractor be ported on languages  like ruby or python??  Is there something inherent in JavaScript we require here?

Comment: NO ! .. not inherently - check this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29983241/use-protractor-with-java

Comment: You can mimic Protractor "like"  behavior to other languages - See this [amazing post](https://confengine.com/selenium-conf-2015/proposal/1356/an-angularjs-testing-framework-for-the-rest-of-us-porting-protractor-to-python)

Comment: Thanks Aditya ...This seems promising..I will look into it.